# Setting proxy to Spring SAML HTTPMetadataProvider

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, proxy, saml

We are using spring-security-saml for our SAML authentication. The app is working fine and when we try to run the app on demo machine, the connection to SAML metadata url is timing out.

we have given the metadata url in our application.yml as

```
security:
   saml2:
      metadata-url: https://dev-715244.oktapreview.com/app/<app_id>/sso/saml/metadata
```

Tried setting the proxy to the jvm  while running the jar but same issue is there. But this URL is reachable through CURL.

Any idea as to how to set proxy details to the HTTP Client used by spring SAML?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to create a bean as follows to your WebSecurityConfig:

```
@Bean
public HttpClient httpClient() {
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient(this.multiThreadedHttpConnectionManager);
    HostConfiguration hostConfiguration = new HostConfiguration();
    hostConfiguration.setProxy("PROXYHOST", PROXYPORT);
    client.setHostConfiguration(hostConfiguration);
    return client;
}
```